# Is QSemaphore enough to make a thread safe analogue of QQueue?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, semaphore

I was trying to make a basic thread safe analogue of QQueue. The idea is that one thread is putting data in queue and the other is processing it. And I've came to a very basic solution.

```
#include <QThread>
#include <QQueue>
#include <QSemaphore>

class AsyncQueue
{
public:
    void enqueue(const int x);
    int dequeue();
private:
    QQueue<int> queue;
    QSemaphore semaphore;
};

int AsyncQueue::dequeue()
{
    semaphore.acquire();
    return queue.dequeue();
}

void AsyncQueue::enqueue(const int x)
{
    queue.enqueue(x);
    semaphore.release();
    return;
}
```

I am new to multithreading. It aces some simplest tests but I wounder if that is enough? Or does the queue require AtomicPointer in case thread will try to enqueue new item when the other is processing the last item of the queue?

Comment: If you aren't forced to use qt components and semaphores you may look at mutexes as well. In particular `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>` does all the work for you and it comes with C++11 so you should be able to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not, there is opportunity for concurrent read/write access to the queue, since there is no critical section guarding the write access to the queue from `enqueue()`. It can always execute since `QSemaphore::release()` wil never block. Therefore, there is plenty of opportunity for `dequeue()` and `enqueue(int)` to be executed concurrently, causing havoc.

The semaphore you have now fulfills the role of signaling to the consumer side of the queue the amount of values present in the queue. You will need a second `QSemaphore` to implement the exclusive access to the underlying `QQueue`, as follows (very superficially tested):

```
#include <QThread>
#include <QQueue>
#include <QSemaphore>

class AsyncQueue
{
public:
  void enqueue(const int x);
  int dequeue();

private:
  QQueue<int> queue;
  QSemaphore itemsInQueue;
  QSemaphore exclusiveAccess{1};
};

int AsyncQueue::dequeue()
{
  itemsInQueue.acquire();
  exclusiveAccess.acquire();
  int result{queue.dequeue()};
  exclusiveAccess.release();
  return result;
}

void AsyncQueue::enqueue(const int x)
{
  exclusiveAccess.acquire();
  queue.enqueue(x);
  exclusiveAccess.release();
  itemsInQueue.release();
}
```

If you have access to a modern compiler, I prefer to use STL counterparts to implement this. [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread), [`std::mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex), [`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard), and [`std::condition_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) are worth looking into in this context.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try as said below.

Basically the documentation says:

> QSharedPointer and QWeakPointer are thread-safe and operate atomically
>   on the pointer value. Different threads can also access the
>   QSharedPointer or QWeakPointer pointing to the same object at the same
>   time without need for locking mechanisms.

So you do not require a locking mechanism.....

*How to:?*

```
    using sInt = QSharedPointer<int>;

    QQueue<sInt> qInt; //Your queue of shared pointer objects.

    qInt.enqueue(QSharedPointer<int>::create(5));
    qInt.enqueue(QSharedPointer<int>::create(6));
    qInt.enqueue(QSharedPointer<int>::create(7));
    qInt.enqueue(QSharedPointer<int>::create(8));

   //To retrieve the value use either data() or get() as shown below.

    sInt value =  qInt.dequeue();
    int *val = value.data();
```